# Setting a string parameter inside struts.xml action from a properties file

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, download, ognl

I've been trying to implement an action which allows the user to download a file with a specific filename. This `filename` is set by passing the action a parameter through `struts.xml` this way:

```xml
<result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
            <param name="inputName">input_document</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=foo.bar</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
```

I have omitted the rest of the  code as I just want to focus on this:

```xml
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=foo.bar</param>
```

That way it works perfectly and lets you download the `foo` file with `.bar` extension.

So here's the deal, I was curious to know wether if **is it possible to retrieve the extension from a properties file and pass it through the parameter**, for example, like this:

```xml
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=foo%{+ getText("EXTENSION_KEY_IN_PROPERTIES_FILE")}</param>
```

I know that `getText("...")` won't work but I just want you to understand what I'm searching for.

I'm currently working with some properties files for global parameters and localization stuff so it would be great if I could retrieve this file extension from one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if your action implements `TextProvider`

```xml
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=foo${getText('EXTENSION_KEY_IN_PROPERTIES_FILE')}</param>
```

Comment: Well it seems the issue was I didn't add the properties file to the project resources properly... worked like a charm when I did. @Roman What does that <![CDATA[]> stands for ?? Thank you :)

Comment: It's used with the text that uses special characters omitted by xml parser when parsed a document. I removed them from the answer.

Comment: Oh, Ok, I'll accept your answer as you point out well that TextProvider must be implemented by the action. Thanks